Debugging qgis-plugin with VS Code: no breakpoints hit
I created a plugin and try to debug it using VS Code. I first tried the "Enable Debug for Visual Studio"-Plugin. When clicking on it, a second QGIS-windows opens which after some seconds outouts a timeout

RuntimeError("timed out waiting for adapter to connect")

I also tried to immediately attach VS Code to the newly opened process. That indeed resulted in VS Code being attached to that process, however QGIS itself still outputs the mentioned exception. Furthermore that second process also outputs these errros:

CRITICAL    Ungültige Datenquelle : C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\debugpy\adapter ist keine gültige oder erkannte Datenquelle.
CRITICAL    Ungültige Datenquelle : C:\Users<myuser>\Documents--for-server ist keine gültige oder erkannte Datenquelle.
CRITICAL    Ungültige Datenquelle : C:\Users<myuser>\Documents\58322 ist keine gültige oder erkannte Datenquelle.
CRITICAL    Ungültige Datenquelle : C:\Users<myuser>\Documents--host ist keine gültige oder erkannte Datenquelle.
CRITICAL    Ungültige Datenquelle : C:\Users<myuser>\Documents\localhost ist keine gültige oder erkannte Datenquelle.
CRITICAL    Ungültige Datenquelle : C:\Users<myuser>\Documents--port ist keine gültige oder erkannte Datenquelle.
CRITICAL    Ungültige Datenquelle : C:\Users<myuser>\Documents\5678 ist keine gültige oder erkannte Datenquelle.
CRITICAL    Ungültige Datenquelle : C:\Users<myuser>\Documents--server-access-token ist keine gültige oder erkannte Datenquelle.
CRITICAL    Ungültige Datenquelle : C:\Users\admin_schumannc\Documents\ad0660fcfe4af1dcc743fb9cf4930147d22443edf088c6ec2c83d5f4c79d9b75 ist keine gültige oder erkannte Datenquelle.

So I completely omited that plugin and just use "attach to process" in VS Code. This works as the debugger seems to be attched. At least I can see my breakpoints be full red, indicating they are found. However when running the plugin, these breakpoints aren't hit at all.
This is my launch.json:
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
           "name": "Python Debugger: Attach using Process Id",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "env": {
                // Path
                "PATH": "C:/OSGeo4/apps/Python39/Scripts;C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qt5/bin;C:/OSGeo4W/apps/Python312/Scripts;C:/OSGeo4W/bin;C:/Windows/system32;C:/Windows;C:/Windows/system32/WBem;C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/bin;C:/OSGeo4W/apps/grass/grass78/lib;C:/OSGeo4/apps/Qt5/bin;C:/OSGeo4/apps/Python312/Scripts",
                // Python
                "PYTHONHOME": "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/Python312",
                "PYTHONPATH": "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/python",
                // GDAL
                "GDAL_DATA": "C:/OSGeo4W/share/gdal",
                "GDAL_DRIVER_PATH": "C:/OSGeo4W/bin/gdalplugins",
                "GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8": "YES",
                // GeoTIFF
                "GEOTIFF_CSV": "C:/OSGeo4W/share/epsg_csv",
                // Qt
                "O4W_QT_BINARIES": "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/Qt5/bin",
                "O4W_QT_DOC": "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/Qt5/doc",
                "O4W_QT_HEADERS": "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/Qt5/include",
                "O4W_QT_LIBRARIES": "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/Qt5/lib",
                "O4W_QT_PLUGINS": "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/Qt5/plugins",
                "O4W_QT_PREFIX": "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/Qt5",
                "O4W_QT_TRANSLATIONS": "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/Qt5/translations",
                "QT_PLUGIN_PATH": "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/qtplugins;C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qt5/plugins",
                // QGIS
                "QGIS_PREFIX_PATH": "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis",
                // Cache
                "VSI_CACHE": "TRUE",
                "VSI_CACHE_SIZE": "1000000"
            },
        }
    ]
}

I also tried to add some pathMappings to the configuration:
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/",
                    "remoteRoot": "C:/Users/<myuser>/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/myqgisplugin"
                }
            ]

However in that case the breakpoints aren't filled red and are - as one may assume - not hit. Of course my workspaceFolder applies to my git-repo where the plugin-code is located.
